# How do I return an array from a dataloader?

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

Here is my GraphQL type:

```
const PoliticalEntity = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'PoliticalEntity',
    fields: () => ({
        id: {
            type: GraphQLID,
            resolve: obj => obj.political_entity_id
        },
        algorithmValues: {
            type: new GraphQLList(AlgorithmValue),
            resolve: (obj, args, context) => {
                context
                    .dataloaders
                    .algorithmValueLoader
                    .load(obj.political_entity_id)
            }
        }
    })
});
```

For each `PoliticalEntity` I have multiple `AlgorithmValues`.  How do I get the dataloader to return multiple values for each key?

The data loader is being called and the query is returning correctly, but I continue to get the error.  `DataLoader must be constructed with a function which accepts Array<key> and returns Promise<Array<value>>, but the function did not return a Promise of an Array of the same length as the Array of keys.`

How do I fix this?

Comment: Your batch load function needs to return an array of arrays the same length as the array of keys it is passed. Please share your loader code, otherwise it's hard to know what exactly is wrong with your code.

Comment: That completely makes sense. Submit an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Wanted to ensure there wasn't something else going on that could be causing that error before posting an answer :)

Answer (score 5):

Your batch load function should return a Promise with an array. As the error indicates, the length of the keys passed to the batch load function must match the length of this result array. If your Loader is fetching an array of items for each key, then the Promise must resolve to an array of arrays.

```
const backLoadFn = (keys) => {
  return Promise.all(keys.map(key => {
    return Model.findAll({ where: { key } })
  }))
}
```